# Scrollview is not showing any content in emulator or phone even though the preview is looking fine SOLVED

Tags: android, android-scrollview, oncreate

Android studio scrollview is not showing any content in emulator or phone even though the Android studio preview is fine. Even the background colour is missing. Although, I'am a noob with Android studio but I think that everything should work in this code and thereby I'm confused.

I have read multiple threads about this problem but non of them answered this question adequately. As instructed to by these answers, I have tried to adjust the width and height settings, and used linear layout as a root, and other tricks, but with little success. However, I think that the linear layout is not blocking the scrollview and the problem is either in this xml file or somewhere else. I have tried to solve this now at least two hours by myself, but I'm turning to more advanced developers to ask for some advice.

The problem was that I had no onCreate method in the Java file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
<LinearLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".StartGame">
-->



<ScrollView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".StartGame">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/eka_teksti"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<!--
</LinearLayout>
-->
```

Here is the relevant Java code

```xml
    package com.jussitamminen.pplpankki;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.View;

    public class StartGame extends AppCompatActivity {


    }
```

And there is the Manifest code also

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.jussitamminen.pplpankki">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".StartGame"
                android:label="Second Activity"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I expect that the scrollview has a background colour and other content as I defined.

here

Comment: Your XML seems fine. Can you post the related JAVA code?

Comment: Here. It is rather short and it might cause the problem However, I followed the video instructions about scrollview and in these videos the java file was untouched.

package com.jussitamminen.pplpankki;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;



public class StartGame extends AppCompatActivity {


}

Comment: I am more interested in what you are doing inside the StartGame class rather than the definition and imports. If that is exactly what your current Java code looks like, no wonder you are not seeing anything.

Comment: Is your StartGame class empty, like you have showed in your question? No onCreate()?

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! I have been a fool ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, you do not have an onCreate() method. There is no linking between your Java class and the XML file.That is why you are seeing nothing.

Add the onCreate to your StartGame class like this.

```
public class StartGame extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. In all guide videos, the scrollview was placed directly in the main activity and thereby the needed link was already there.

Answer (score 0):

Update Your scrollview like this, make height and width match_parent and add fillViewport= true

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".StartGame">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/eka_teksti"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried your's trick but it didn't worked. What the android:fillViewport="true" should do? I didn't saw it on examples that I found from internet. And do you kwon the difference between fill_parent and match_parent? Thank you anyway.